# Can you target classes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, selector

What I want to do is `$('.class.img').css('cellpadding', variable);`

It doesn't seem to be working. I tried googling to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to apply it to an image inside the element with the given class.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want the CSS definition for that class ? Do you want to apply some CSS to elements with that class?

Comment: $('.cellBox:img').css("padding", cellPadding);                           specifically im trying to do this, where cellPadding is a variable, im trying to apply it to an image inside a div with class'cellBox'

Comment: @Gazow: The correct CSS syntax for an `img` element with the "cellBox" class is `img.cellBox`. So: `$("img.cellBox").css("padding", cellPadding);` But note that `css` does **not** support CSS shorthand properties like `padding`.

Comment: @TJ, im trying to apply it to images that are children of the .cellBox Class, sorry i messed this question up pretty bad, i was googling like 10 different things trying to get this working heh. the images are created dynamically with a for loop so they do not have class or id

Comment: ok, yeah i guess i messed this whole thing up, i think its fixed now thanks

Comment: @gazow: Ah, okay; I've updated my answer to explain how you do that.

Comment: @gazow the selector you r using is wrong,i guess it should be `$('.cellBox img').css('padding',cellPadding);` if you're trying to change the css of image which is child of element having class 'cellBox'. Try this and good luck bro...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS applies the styling properties inline as in `style="..."` and does not modify the .class itself.

`$('.class').css` does not do anything.

`$('.class').css('color','red')` writes a color style

`$('.class').css('color')` reads the color style

So to target your `img` elements within an element with class "cellBox":

```
var borderx = "1px solid red";
$('.cellbox img').css('border',borderx);
```

(That sets `border`, but you can set `padding` the same way.)

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/SBjfp/2/

(Note that the jQuery documentation says that shorthand properties like `padding` or `border` are [not supported](http://api.jquery.com/css/); this mostly applies to *getting* the properties; *setting* [as above] usually works because it's supported by the underlying browser's implementation.)

Comment: Now that this answer is essentially correct, I've taken the liberty of copying the selector bit actually *into* the answer in case of link rot, and flagging up what the docs say about shorthand properties. Also cleaned up a bunch of chaff comments that are no longer relevant to the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector engine works perfectly well with class selectors.

The only thing clearly wrong with this (there might be other things, but you haven't provided any context (such as what the document looks like or *when* the statement is run)) is that `css` is a function, and you aren't *calling* it (i.e. `css('foo')`).